# Problem on How to correctly include / exclude sources for SonarQube in a multimodule project

Tags: maven, sonarqube

We have projects with a structure like this ( a root pom and 2 sub modules ) :

- local-module
- implementation-module
  pom.xml

By default sonar seems to use these sources :

```
<sonar.sources>pom.xml,src/main,src/test</sonar.sources>
```

We want to analyse YML files or other files in others locations.

But after trying various configuration according to https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/

This one :

```
    <sonar.sources>.</sonar.sources>
    <sonar.tests>src/test/java</sonar.tests>
    <sonar.test.inclusions>src/test/java</sonar.test.inclusions>
    <sonar.exclusions>src/test/java</sonar.exclusions>
```

produces the following error :

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1398:sonar (default-cli) on project sample: null: MojoExecutionException: NullPointerException
```

and this one :

```
<sonar.sources>.</sonar.sources>
<sonar.test.exclusions>src/test/java</sonar.test.exclusions>
```

produces :

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1398:sonar (default-cli) on project pew-fwk-sample: File sample-impl/src/test/java/com/xxx/sample/FeaturesTest.java can't be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files -> [Help 1]
```

Do you have any ideas on the solutions ?

Comment: You should remove the entry with `.` only...

Answer (score 0):

I would not change to many parameters at once. Some of these properties are provided by the maven plugin and should not need to be changed. I would start just using the exclusions parameter. Note that it uses some ant style pattern to exclude files. If you don't provide it it will only apply to that specific file or folder. The page you linked contains some example at the bottom:

```
# Exclude all classes ending by "Bean"
# Matches org/sonar.api/MyBean.java, org/sonar/util/MyOtherBean.java, org/sonar/util/MyDTO.java, etc.
sonar.exclusions=**/*Bean.java,**/*DTO.java

# Exclude all classes in the "src/main/java/org/sonar" directory
# Matches src/main/java/org/sonar/MyClass.java, src/main/java/org/sonar/MyOtherClass.java
# But does not match src/main/java/org/sonar/util/MyClassUtil.java
sonar.exclusions=src/main/java/org/sonar/*

# Exclude all COBOL programs in the "bank" directory and its sub-directories
# Matches bank/ZTR00021.cbl, bank/data/CBR00354.cbl, bank/data/REM012345.cob
sonar.exclusions=bank/**/*

# Exclude all COBOL programs in the "bank" directory and its sub-directories whose extension is .cbl
# Matches bank/ZTR00021.cbl, bank/data/CBR00354.cbl
sonar.exclusions=bank/**/*.cbl
```

So something like `<sonar.exclusions>src/main/java/**/*</sonar.exclusions>` should exclude all sources. Above is an example to only exclude Dto classes. Usually the exclusions are enough to narrow the focus down. But includes work the same way should you want to go that way.